# Kafka: Increased partitions could not be assigned in next rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I meet a strange thing about Kafka rebalance. If I increase partitions on a topic, which subscribed by some java consumers(in same one group), there is no consumer rebalance occur. After that, I try to cause a rebalance by starting a new consumer (or kill one), and the new increased partitions could not be assigned in this rebalance. I found that the new partitions could only be assigned after I stop all consumers and start them. I don't know if it's normal or if there is any explanation for it.

Below is my test on my computer:

1.Start Kafka, ZK. Create a normal topic(**test-topic**) with 1 partitions

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --create --topic test-topic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config retention.ms=604800000
```

2.Start 2 java consumers (**C1**, **C2**), subscribe **test-topic**

3.Increase 2 partitions of **test-topic**

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --alter --topic test-topic --partitions 3
```

There is no rebalance occur in **C1**, **C2**

4.Start a new consumer **C3** to subscribed test-topic. Rebalance occur, but only partition **test-topic-0** involved in reassign, neither **test-topic-1** or **test-topic-2** involved.

5.I try to cause rebalance by stopping **C2** and **C3**. However **test-topic-1** and **test-topic-2** are still not be assigned.

6.Stop all running consumers, and then start them. All **test-topic-0,1,2** are assigned normally.

**kafka & java api version**: kafka_2.12-2.0.0 (I also tried kafka_2.11-1.0.0 and kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1, same result)

**zookeeper**: 3.4.13

**consumer code**:

```java
public class KafkaConsumerThread extends Thread {
    // consumer settings
    public static org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer<String, String> createNativeConsumer(String groupName, String kafkaBootstrap) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrap);
        props.put("group.id", groupName);
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", true);
        props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        return new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("Start consumer ..");
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName), consumerRebalanceListener);
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                receivedRecordNumber.addAndGet(records.count());
                Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> iterator = records.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    ConsumerRecord<String, String> record = iterator.next();
                    log.info("Receive [key:{}][value:{}]", record.key(), record.value());
                }
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                log.info("no data");
            }
        }
        consumer.close();
    }
}
```

---

Thanks for @Aftab Virtual's comment. I test again and wait for a longer time. About 5 minutes after the first consumer started, an rebalance did automatically raise and all partitions **test-topic-0,1,2** reassigned. Therefore, Kafka do have an auto rebalance after alter partitions.

Furthermore, I followed @Aftab Virtual's advise to change `leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds` to 30. However the rebalance involved all partitions occur about 3 minutes after partition increased. I do add settings for broker:

```
auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 30
```

I don't know what is the mechanism for this rebalance. And there is no more logs for this rebalance:

```
[2018-10-18 11:32:47,958] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group test-group with old generation 4 (__consumer_offsets-12) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-10-18 11:32:50,963] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Stabilized group test-group generation 5 (__consumer_offsets-12) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2018-10-18 11:32:50,964] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Assignment received from leader for group test-group for generation 5 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Comment: I'm speculating, but this sounds like a bug.  Notification for rebalance is supposed to happen on consumer stopping or starting, but then steps #4 and #5 should have triggered a full rebalance. If what you're saying is true, it seems somehow the original consumers are "locking" the state, and only when they're all gone is when that state is released, and new consumers will finally see the new partitions.

Comment: By default broker config parameter auto.leader.rebalance.enable is true. So partitions should automatically rebalance. 
But, by default this rebalance happen after every 5 minutes which is handled by parameter leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds. To make it more frequent you can update this parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeking advice from Kafka team and some Kafka users, I got the explanation for my test result. It's not a bug.

The increasing of the partitions will marked the metadata.updateNeeded=true. However this will not really trigger a update till the next metadata expire time (the default `metadata.max.age.ms` is 5*60*1000 ms). Before the leader of the group update its metadata, the rebalance caused by changing consumer number will not involved the new partitions.

I decreased `metadata.max.age.ms` to 30 seconds and Kafka became more sensitive to partitions increasing.